# Flutter APP - Miui /Hyper O/S notification style causing issues for system tray icon

Tags: flutter

My Flutter app sends push notifications. I've noticed the app's system tray icon only displays correctly when I use the "Classic" notification style on my android device (Hyper O/S UI). When I choose "Android", the icon changes to a white square.

Does anyone know why this might be? Is this a Hyper O/S error or a Flutter thing?

Here's a link to a screenshot of the issue:

https://ibb.co/dbs6DN0